# Disable PHPStorm new file branding

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpstorm

When I create a new file using PhpStorm it creates it's own comment at the top, this would be fine however when using codeigniter comments using /* */ do not work, anyway to disable this? if not i'm going to have to get a new editor.

Here is what I mean

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Josh
 * Date: 28/02/2015
 * Time: 22:53
*/
```

Comment: Comments do not work in CodeIgniter??

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Windows: Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Includes (TAB) -> PHP File Header

Mac: Go to PhpStorm -> Preferences -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Includes (TAB) -> PHP File Header

And then you can edit it or remove it, or whatever you wanna do :)

Comment: Cheers for this tip. Would be nice if they simply didn't put advertising clutter in my code, given I've paid for the product already, but at least I can get rid now :-)

Comment: Thank you for this straightforward answer... why is this setting so hidden?

Answer (score 10):

settings > editor > file and code templates > includes(tab) > php file header

I recommend to erase content instead of deleting this element

Answer (score 0):

Instead of erasing the content you can just comment it out by surrounding it with `{#...#}` because it uses [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Velocity_Template_Language_VTL:_An_Introduction) template language.